# Incompatible types in string

Tags: android

```
Resources r1 = getResources();
String[] refrigerant = r1.getStringArray(R.array.refrigerant);

if (refrigerant == "")
{
    if (et1.getText().toString() == refrigerant[i3]
    {
         flag = true;                               
    }
```

I got the error incompatible  operand types String[] and string
please give me solution.

Answer (score 4):

refrigerant is an array, but here refrigerant == "" you compare and array with "", which is not possible. You could check for null and refrigerant.length >0

Answer (score 1):

If refrigerant is an String array you can not compare it as an empty String.

Try

```
if(refrigerant == null || refrigerant.length == 0){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note also that comparing Strings using `==` as in your second `if` clause will very often not work, as it tests object identity. You usually want to use `string1.equals(string2)`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are trying to compare a string array to a string in your first "if" statement